# Cross-platform building of code that uses sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer

Tags: java, awt

I use the following import in my code:

```
import sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer;
```

On Windows this class is located in `rt.jar` so I can build the whole app. On Mac there is no such class so I can't.

How to change the project to support cross-platform building? I use Gradle, maybe a dependency is needed?

Comment: Don't import that. It'll only be available on Windows since it contains native Windows functionality.

Comment: @Kayaman , without `import` I can't use it :(

Comment: And you shouldn't be using it, because it's not a cross platform class and it's not even meant for developers since it's a `sun.*` class. Either stop using it or forget running your code on anything but Windows.